# Allow Background Activity for this App in Foreground Service Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xamarin.android

I am running a foreground service in android 10 and 11. But I have issue in my Oppo android 11. Issue is that the execution of any process is stopped after some time because the Allow Background Activity is not enabled for this app in setting. If I allow it then the foreground service works fine. I don't know how to check that if the Allow background activity is enabled or not and how to move to that specific intent. I have search alot but didn't found any solution.
The picture of the app setting is here.

[The picture of the app setting is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvA4.jpg)

The Android Manifest file permissions are here.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Add this permission, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

Comment: You don't need to request for this permssion at runtime, it will be automatically granted as It is not a Sensitive permission.

Comment: @VaibhavGoyal I have added this also but not working

Comment: Can you show your service class' code?

Comment: Try using this for requesting background location permissions: https://github.com/warting/permissions-ui